# How to import npm libraries in React

Tags: reactjs, require, npm-package

I'm trying to import the [createjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/createjs) lib into my react project.

So I installed it via `npm install createjs --save`

And there is a folder called `createjs` in `node_modules`.

But when I try to import it with `require("createjs")` it says:

"Module not found: Can't resolve 'createjs.js' in '...client/src'"

my package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "createjs": "^1.0.1",
    "createjs-easeljs": "^0.8.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-nav2djs": "0.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "ros2d": "^0.9.0",
    "roslib": "^1.0.1",
    "vb-react-nav2djs": "0.0.4"
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your package.json file

Comment: When i install new lib i use in the react component with....
import { createjs } from 'createjs' ; i think so...  
other people ask the same :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773434/how-to-include-createjs-library-into-reactjs-project

Comment: Can't really do much without knowing more about your enviroment, what bundler are you using?

Comment: I'm using the standard create-react-app package via `npx create-react-app` so should be the latest version

Comment: If you haven't restarted your dev server, the new dependencies won't be available. Give that a try if you haven't already.

Comment: I did try that already

Comment: are you still facing the issue?

Comment: yes, i do, I'm thinking of just giving up and trying to import it over index.html

Comment: maybe try: import * as createjs from 'createjs';